# Deploying model

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I just finished training a categorizer model exactly the way described in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/MiniCat but I am not sure how to use the model to make predictions.

[Trained model in the direction Train](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTxuA.png)

[Data in the directory Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TY9G.png)

I'm really new to this and I don't know where to start. I read something about deploying model in https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/deploying-models but how do I even create a SavedModel.

Any answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So in the folder where you got the trained model, you just need to load that model in your session. First create a saver (you can also use it for laoding)

```
train_saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

Now inside your session:

```
train_saver.restore(sess, 'path/to/model/doc_classifier_cnn_model.ckpt')
```

Then just feed the tensors with feed_dict.

Other option is to create a protobuf file (.pb) but in doing so you will have to load the model as I said.

Comment: Dumb question, do I have to make a python script for this?

Comment: I know of no dumb questions. You will have to write python code to run those lines yes.

Comment: Just to confirm, it's possible to deploy the model that can predict new dataset if I follow the steps above or the one in tensorflow/google?

Comment: Yeah of course, that is the main purpose of machine learning.

Comment: You should check [this documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#save_variables) for further insight on how to save and restore variables in TensorFlow using Python. SavedModel structure is explained below in the same document.